# Android : Screen Size

Tags: android

I'm working on android application and got in trouble of multiple screen support. I developed the app for 1080x1920 and when i tested the app on my friends Micromax Unite 2 with resolution of 480x800, it was something else. So i made two folders in the layout as:

```
layout-1080x1920
layout-480x800
```

thinking that the 480x800 device will pick up the layout-480x800 folder. But no it used the layout-1080x1920. So what should i do? So that the device having resolution of 480x800 works on layout-480x800

Comment: This is [well-documented](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on the Android site

Comment: hi cricket_007 no dude it doesn't work in my case

Comment: **What** doesn't work? There is a lot to read there. Hint: `layout-1080x1920` is not a valid resource folder name

Comment: listen i tried layout-normal ok and the resolution 1080x1920 and 480x800 they both come under the same category, so when i do the preview of 480x800 and make some changes to it then the 1080x1920 gets disturbed :(

Comment: Resolution-dependent resource directories have been obsolete for quite some time. Resolution itself is usually meaningless. Focus on screen size as measured in density-independent pixels (dp). "1080x1920 and 480x800 they both come under the same category" -- that is entirely possible, if the devices are about the same physical size.

Comment: so how to do it, how to concentrate on the dp

Comment: `layout-normal` is the same as just `layout`. If you want to focus on dp, then you should be using `lhdpi` and `mdpi` and `xhdpi` and `xxhdpi`, as perfectly explained in that link if you actually read it.

Comment: i read and created the folders like that

Comment: @cricket_007 if i create layout-normal then all resolutions except tablets fall under it. so if i make change to a 1080x1920 display then 480x800 gets scattered and vice versa

Comment: The only reason tablets wouldn't fall under it is if you have some **other** layout folder deciding what to do for tablets. For example, if you only have a `res/layout` and nothing else, then all layouts will be used from there.

Comment: i'm not concerened about tablets. My question is very simple how can i design for 480x800 and 1080x1920. Galaxy S4 and Micromax Unit 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest naming the folders as such:

```
layout-sw600dp
```

Where **sw600dp** means Screen Width 600dp. This layout folder will be used by devices with screen widths of 600dp or more (typically all 7-10 inch tablets, or just very dense screen). And when you are targeting for the phone use just the layout folder without any specified criteria. All phones not matching the sw600dp will use the default layout resources. Possibly also consider using

```
layout-sw600dp-port
```

if you need to use specific layouts for portrait orientation, likewise you can do

```
layout-sw600dp-land
```

if you wanted to specified layouts for landscape.

The link cricket_007 provided is where I learned this information

Note that 1080x1920 equates to about 540 x 960 dp in dp measurement, which is why I suggested to use the particular 600dp for width

Comment: listen tell me how do i work with 480x800 and 1080x1920 in simple steps.

Comment: I believe I have. Create resources (layouts) specifically for 1080x1920 and store them in a folder called layout-sw600dp. Create resources (layouts) specifically for 480x800 and store those in the default layout folder. This way, on your 1080x1920 device, it will use the layout resources in the folder layout-sw600dp and the smaller devices (phones) will use the default layout folder for it's layout resources.

Comment: and say for example u have another resolutions 480x854,320x480,1440x2560,720x1280 how is ur app gonna support those

Comment: 480x854, 320x480 all will fall into the default layout bucket. 1440x2560 and 720x1280  (I believe) will fall under the layout-sw600dp bucket. I would test all these screen densities via emulators too of course.

Comment: Choosing to use layout qualifiers like this is generic and the screens size will dictate which is used, so you don't need to target EXACT dimensions with your particular layouts

Comment: i just created folder layout-sw600dp and it is giving me preview of tablets why??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108317/discussion-between-akashdeep-singh-and-lucas-crawford).

Answer (score 0):

giving the folder names pixel according to [android screen support dev page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Even if you know all possible resolutions for every device, the android system takes those *xml files/drawables etc specified by their DPI, not PX. Those dpi resolutions still can change on runtime, such as, when your activity uses a tool bar (which is not part of your dpi resolution). Name your folders layout-xlarge, layout-large, layout-normal, layout-small for *xml layouts. I suggest to put 4 different xml files with same name in each of them and try it again for different devices.